# About measurability of the interior of a measurable set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a doubt. The following assertion is true?

> If $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable (by Lebesgue), then $\mathrm{int}(X)$ is measurable and $|X| = |\mathrm{int} (X)|$.

If not, do you can give me a counter-example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interiors are open, and hence measurable. However, your equality need not hold: for example, in $\Bbb{R}$ the irrationals have infinite measure but empty interior.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! But do you can to conclude that if $|X| > 0$ (in $\mathbb{R}$), then $X$ has a open interval?

Comment: Ok, nice. I see that your example show me this!